# Bolt: group permissions

Tags: bolt-cms

I have a page in Bolt and want to know if it's possible it can be edited by 2 different persons, now i can only be done by the owner. These persons cannot be chief-editors. Maybe I can set a group permission?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a good practice

Define a new permissions group and set up a custom authorization for your contentype.

[here](https://docs.bolt.cm/permissions) it's a explanation for to do this